# Format phone number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, format, phone-number

I need to format phone number for example by `replace()`:

**From:** `+48 XX XXX XX XX` where `X` is a number.

Example: `+48 12 345 67 89`

**To:** `+48 XXX XXX XXX`

Example: `+48 123 456 789`

---

**Edit:**

My work:

- First, I tried to remove the spaces in string:
  `phone.replace(' ', '');`:

Before: `+48 12 312 31 23`

After: `+4812 312 31 23`

Conclusion: Something is wrong because it only formatted the first space instead of everything.

- I also tried to separate it into parts, based on other questions about regex:

`phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/gi, '$1 $2 $3 $4');` and

`phone.replace(/(\d{3})" "(\d{3})" "(\d{3})" "(\d{3})/gi, '$1 $2 $3 $4');`

and many other configurations like this.

Before: `+48 12 312 31 23`

After: `+48 12 312 31 23`

Conclusion: For sure, something is wrong, there is no change. The problem is with the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement approach here:

```js
var input = "+48 12 345 67 89";
var output = input.replace(/\s+/g, "")
                  .replace(/^(\+\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/, "$1 $2 $3 $4");
console.log(input + " => " + output);
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI - `string.replace()` will only replace the first instance of whatever you want to replace whereas `string.replaceAll()` will replace all instances.